# BDD Gherkin Scripts: Same group of scenarions against multiple roles

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I have a feature with a number of scenarios that need to be tested where the user is logged in as a number of possible roles (and the outcome should be the same).

Is it possible to put an Examples table into the background? For example:

```
Feature: My general set of tests

Background:
Given I am logged in 
And I am logged in as <role>

Examples:
| role    |
| Sales   |
| Support |
| Admin   |
| Auditor |

Scenario: tests1 blah...

Scenario Outline: tests 2 blah...
```

So what I want to do is iterate through the who feature file with a different Background context rather than having to maintain a separate feature file for each role. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that BDD isn't actually about testing. We're using examples to *illustrate* the behaviour we want. All you need is one scenario which provides an example of the behaviour.

If one of the roles provides different behaviour, then have an example of that behaviour too.

A better place to test that the outcomes are the same for all the roles might be at a unit-testing level, in whichever class links the roles to different outcomes. And of course, you can manually test it. The chances are very good that if you get it right and it works manually, it isn't going to break without breaking the one example you've got. It's enough.

If you try and cover every permutation of every role like this, you'll end up with a very slow build and far too many scenarios, none of which are interesting any more. Think in terms of examples of what you're trying to illustrate, rather than tests, and you'll have an easier time.

Comment: To this point I think you are correct. I think the solution is to use a single typical role and run the scenarios on that, and have a single scenario that runs through all role options ensure they work on a specific single function in that feature.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The closest you could get would be a step definition "I am logged in in one of the usual roles (Sales, Support, Admin, Auditor)" where the actual role is chosen at random every time. This would of course make your tests non-deterministic, which might be acceptable if you are 100% positive that this role really has absolutely no effect on the outcome. Of course in that case you should rather consider not mentioning the role at all in your scenarios.